# If you had stayed, this would never happen/have happened

Tags: present-perfect

Below is just an example sentence from a dictionary, so I have no context for it:

> If you had stayed, this would never have happened

Would it be grammatically correct and have the same meaning if the simple present were used instead of the present perfect:

> If you had stayed, this would never happen

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is grammatically correct, but it does not mean the same thing.

"this would never *have* happened" is about the present perfect "this *has* happened".  It's about something that actually did happen in the past.

The simple present "this would never happen" is about general truths, like "this happens".  Presumably it has happened in the past, maybe it is happening right now, and it will probably happen again in the future.